Hanging indents not working in PowerPoint
I am currently working on making an APA-7 formatted slideshow in PowerPoint. As part of that, I am required to include a reference list slide. To comply with the format, the reference list must have a half-inch hanging indent.
When I set the indentation to "Hanging" (via Paragraph > Indentation > Special), it does nothing. Here's a screenshot with the Paragraph options open to show what I mean:

How do I get the hanging indent to work?
If it helps, first-line indents still seem to work; it's just hanging indents that are broken.

If you want to do this via the paragraph options, you need to add indentation before the text:


LOL, I like this better than my own answer below.  Thanks!

You need to use the little gadget on the ruler to set the indent. After you've done that, you can alter the indent amount by sliding the gadget around OR use the dialog you've shown above.

